# How to set transparency to majority matplotlib binary scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with an imbalanced dataset - like 99.9:0.1 - and just want to see the 2 dimensional layout after PCA. 'Y', the target, is an array of binary values either 0 or 1.
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = pca[:,0]
y = pca[:,1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
colors = ['yellow', 'red']
plt.scatter(x, y, c=Y, cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors), marker='x')
```

The problem is that the result of the above code creates a scatter plot that majority(0, yellow) covers nearly every minority(1, red). I just can't see them.
I know I can use 'alpha' to set opacity, but that would change both 0 and 1.

I want 0 to be transparent while 1 is opaque or 1 to be above 0. Either way, I can see where every 1 is.
Is there a way to do so?

---

**Update**

I just realized I could solve the custom opacity issue with RGBa.
Yet, I'd still like to know how to put 1s above 0s.

Comment: Try putting all your red data points at the end of your x, y and Y vector

Comment: @c-wilson Never thought to modify the dataset! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about calling scatter separately for the two sets?

```
plt.scatter(x[Y==0], y[Y==0], c=colors[0], marker='x')
plt.scatter(x[Y==1], y[Y==1], c=colors[1], marker='x')
```

The order you call is the order they'll plot.

Comment: Great idea! Guess I can use this in the future. But, I'm not sure I could implement it right now. PCA `fit_transform`ed only X. So, my x, y after PCA has no Y in it. x, y, and Y are in the same order. I guess I could use this and go through another step to separate [Y==0]s and [Y==1]s in both x and y. Thanks!